# Cancelling $interval.cancel based on id passed in $interval.timer

Tags: angularjs, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

In the below given code, we are calling `startTimer` function , where we use `$interval` to trigger the request to backend until we get the `data.status == "complete"` ;and once status is completed ,we set the `flag = true` and flag will lead to trigger the watch and it calls the `$scope.stop` function to cancel the timer using `$interval.cancel`.

But here issue arises i.e. , `$interval.cancel` doesn't know which timer to stop first.

When there are multiple request to call the timer based on id, the completed timer based on that id should get cancelled.

So my question is **How to cancel the timer based on the id**.

```
angular.module('timerApp', ['timerApp.controllers']);
angular.module('timerApp.controllers', []).controller('timerController', ['$scope', '$interval',
    function($scope, $interval) {
        var timer;
        var time = 10;
        $scope.countdown = time;
        $scope.startTimer = function(id) {
            timer = $interval(function(id) {
                $scope.countdown--;
                //res is response from my backend
                someRestService(id).then(res);
                var data = res;
                if (data.status = "complete") {
                    $scope.timerFlag = true;
                }
            }, 15000);

        };

    }
    $scope.stopTimer = function() {
        $interval.cancel(timer);
    };

    $scope.$watch() {
        if ($scope.timerFlag == true) {
            $scope.stopTimer();

        }

    }
]);
```

scenario :

```
 RestapiHit/627 
 RestapiHit/628
 RestapiHit/629
```

it will call the 627 request and finish the process and then when about to cancel using `$interval.cance`l it goes for latest one and cancel the 629 but not 627

Comment: Taka  a look at my answer, i am not sure if it'll give some error but the approach should suffice. In case, you need a working code , you can create a demo code on plunkr.com and let  me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at:

```
angular.module('timerApp', ['timerApp.controllers']);
angular.module('timerApp.controllers', []).controller('timerController', ['$scope', '$interval',
    function($scope, $interval) {
        var timer= {} ;
        var time = 10;
        $scope.countdown = time;
        $scope.startTimer = function(id) {
            timer[id] = $interval(function(id) {
                $scope.countdown--;
                //res is response from my backend
                someRestService(id).then(res);
                var data = res;
                if (data.status = "complete") {
                    $scope.stopTimer(id);
                }
            }, 15000);

        };

    }
    $scope.stopTimer = function(id) {
        $interval.cancel(timer[id]);
        delete timer[id];
    };

]);
```

Right now, you just have one `timer` value assigned as it is declared at controller level. But since, you might have multiple calls for `$interval` so i think this approach should work better.